# Why Is It So Obvious that a$ $5-vertices Complete Graph Can't be imbedded in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

While reading a Munkres topology textbook, at the chapter of Dimension Theory, the wirter said : complete graph on five vertices cannot be imbedded in $\Bbb R^2$ but doesn't provide any ground but says "it's intuitively obvious"

Why is it so obvious?

Comment: There's an essentially unique way to embed a complete graph on 3 vertices. This is a triangle. Now when you add a fourth vertex, it can either go on the inside or the outside and the resulting graph is essentially unique. However, when you then try to add a fifth vertex, no matter where you put it, it can't connect to he previous 4 vertices. A rigorous proof would use the Jordan separation theorem.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Why would you post that as a comment, when it's clearly an answer?

Comment: "when you then try to add a fifth vertex, no matter where you put it, it can't connect to 't'he previous 4 vertices." I still doesn't get this part of  your comment. I still can draw 4 edges between the new fift-th one and the previous vertices..I think.

Comment: @there's no clear formula for given v and e where each of them are cardinality of edge and vertex, the minimum dimension d of euclidean space represented in v and e to make the embedding available?

Comment: @MorganRodgers The problem in that problem is vertex embedding.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine K4 for a moment. In order to build K5 out of K4, we add a new vertex $(V)$ and connect it with an edge to each of the other vertices.

[image]

If we put $V$ in region A, we can't connect $V$ to the bottom right vertex without crossing an existing edge. Identical arguments hold for B and C. If we put $V$ in region $D$, then we can't connect $V$ to the central vertex without crossing an edge.

Comment: @Caelan_Ravel Could you help me with this problem too? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32726/optimal-dimension-of-graphvertex-embedding 

It has a same context

Answer (score 2):

There's an essentially unique way to embed a complete graph on 3 vertices. This is a triangle. Now when you add a fourth vertex, it can either go on the inside or the outside and the resulting graph is essentially unique. However, when you then try to add a fifth vertex, no matter where you put it, it can't connect to he previous 4 vertices. A rigorous proof would use the Jordan separation theorem.